# Datatables: sorting in real time

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using a datatable that is not using ajax, and I need the ability to re-sort the columns as they are changed by the client. Is this possible? The table has many inputs, and sorting works fine when the table is loaded, but when these input values are changed from the browser, sorting doesn't interpret the new values (it just keeps sorting 'thinking' the old ones are still there)... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On http://www.datatables.net/ref i found the Parameter `fnDraw`.

This will possibly help to get the new values interpreted.

If it does not help, please create an example at http://jsfiddle.net/ that shows your code.